# Wait for Executors

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

THere is a loop to borrow Objects from A GenericObjectPool and submit to a Executor in each loop. Then, the caller has to wait for all Exectuors to complete.

Here is present code -

```
private ImplClass implObject;
private Future future;

for (Iterator iter = anArrayList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {

    //Gets a GenericObjectPool Object
    implObject = (ImplClass) this.getImplPool().borrowObject();

    future = getExecutorServices().submit(implObject);
}


// Wait for Exectuor to complete
while (!future.isDone()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(Global.WaitTime());

    } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
    }
}
```

But this is wrong as future waits for only last Thread. Should I create an Array of Futures to monitor each executor  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecutorService has a specific method for that: [ExecutorService.invokeAll(tasks)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

The [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) mentioned in Ralf's answer can also be helpful - it allows you to process results by the caller thread as they arrive.

Comment: Right, even if that Executor is used in other places, `invokeAll(tasks)` will only wait on the futures resulting from _tasks_. It will also silenty swallow `ExecutionException`s coming from the task’s code.

Comment: Some comments got removed.. Ralf can you please re paste that link ?

Comment: Yeah, helpful people deleted that non-answer. The sample code was here: http://nsreekanth.blogspot.de/2010/12/java5-completionservice-makes-waiting.html. But actually, I think the other solutions based on invokeAll are better here.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?:

```
List<Callable> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable>();
for (Iterator iter = anArrayList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
    //Gets a GenericObjectPool Object
    implObject = (ImplClass) this.getImplPool().borrowObject();      
    tasks.add(implObject);
}
List<Future<Object>> futures = getExecutorServices().invokeAll(tasks);
```

Comment: I am thinking about this - The loop is on Runnable Size (anArrayList) which is greater thatn GenericObjectPool size.So borrowing Object from GenericObjectpool will stop the Thread once its threshold is reached. A possible solution that I can think here is looping on Pool Size instead so that we come out of loop ..

Comment: As you dont seem to be using anArrayList in your loop, cant you get the size of the object pool and simply loop until the maximum allowable is reached?  ie: while(count++ < objectPoolsize) { do work }